# Write Custom query to search translation with i18n Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rubygems, translation, rails-i18n

I am using gem 'i18n-active_record' to store dynamic translation in db which is working fine but now I need to fetch translation with one more parameter along with locale
Like I have two dashboard success and Improvement so same key with same locale can be stored in db with different dashboard value

like

row 1 in db.   locale: 'en', key: 'hello', value: 'Hello Success', **dashboard: 'success'**

row 2 in db.   locale: 'en', key: 'hello', value: 'Hello Improvement', **dashboard: 'failure'**

Now I need
when I call **t(:hello)** it return translation based on current dashboard

**Like If in in success dashboard t(:hello) should be = 'Hello Success'**

**if i am failure dashboard t(:hello) should be = 'Hello Improvement'**

So how and where I can update t method to query translation based on with one more attribute
Any help much appreciated

Comment: I think a better approach would be to change the keys and not use the same for different values. If you run into issues later it will be hard to debug since you use the same key for multiple values.

Comment: @Hackman Actually dashboard is dynamic we can create any number of dashboard but key remain same thats why I need such approach